# How to change direction of a circle in pygame when hitting a "wall"

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like to know how to change directions of a square when it hits a "wall" with pygame. Below is my code:

```
"""

    Date: Nov 4, 2020

    Description: Animating Shapes with pygame
"""


import pygame


def main():
    '''This function defines the 'mainline logic' for our game.'''
    # I - INITIALIZE
    pygame.init()

    # DISPLAY
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Crazy Shapes Animation")

    # ENTITIES
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((255, 255, 255))  # white background

    # Make a red 25 x 25 box
    red_box = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
    red_box = red_box.convert()
    red_box.fill((255, 0, 0))

    # A - ACTION (broken into ALTER steps)

    # ASSIGN
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True

    red_box_x = 0  # Assign starting (x,y)
    red_box_y = 200  # for our red box

    # LOOP
    while keepGoing:

        # TIMER
        clock.tick(30)

        # EVENT HANDLING
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False

        # change x coordinate of box
        red_box_x += 5
        # check boundaries, to reset box to left-side
        if red_box_x > screen.get_width():
            red_box_x = 0

        # REFRESH (update window)
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(red_box, (red_box_x, red_box_y))  # blit box at new (x,y) location
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Close the game window
    pygame.quit()


# Call the main function
main()
```

When it hits the far right wall, I want it to reverse direction and go back towards the far left wall. Then it continues hitting the walls infinitely. This is kind of for a school assignment, and I couldn't find any solutions online, so it'd be great if you could help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable for the movement (`move_x`) instead of the constant. Invert the value of the variable (`move_x *= -1`) when the object hits a wall:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    move_x = 5

    # LOOP
    while keepGoing:
        # [...]

        # change x coordinate of box
        red_box_x += move_x
        # check boundaries, to reset box to left-side
        if red_box_x >= screen.get_width():
            red_box_x = screen.get_width()
            move_x *= -1
        if red_box_x <= 0:
            red_box_x = 0
            move_x *= -1

        # [...]
```

Comment: Oh... I see now! Thank you so much for your help, I can't believe that I didn't think of that... I will accept this as the answer as soon as the cooldown ends, thank you so much again!